# Python example for Wacom tablets

Tags: python, pyqt, qevent, wacom

Wacom has no official python SDK.
Nevertheless, PyQt has a QTabletEvent that handles these tablets.

Alas, I found no working python example of this.

One can see a c++ example [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-tablet-example.html).

Can anyone please refer me to a python example?

Comment: With a small amount of effort, you should be able to directly translate the C++ example to Python. It's likely your current question will be closed as off-topic but I'd like to point out that a question regarding your attempt to translate the c++ example (for example if you get stuck or something doesn't work) would likely be on topic provided it was specific and you could provide code showing your attempt.

Comment: fair enough. Although, before I start to do it myself, I was wondering, maybe there is already a python script out there that I've missed during my searches.

Comment: There may be one (I'm honestly unsure), but requests for resources are considered off-topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 6):

I did it this way for my WACOM Intuos ART tablet:

Simply inherit a QWidget class and define the tabletEvent() method to handle the received QTabletEvent events.

Don't forget to accept the handled tablet events by calling the tabletEvent.accept() method at the end of the handler.

**Example:**

(handling *TabletPress*, *TabletRelease* and *TabletMove* events)
A *TabletPress* event is generated when the pen is touching the tablet surface, and a *TabletRelease* event is generated when the pen is leaving the tablet surface.
Between these events a flow of *TabletMove* events are generated.

With each received QTabletEvent, you'll get the pen position and the pen pressure. (No Tilt information on my tablet)

Note that I was obliged to resize the sample window at full desktop size to get table events from all the overall tablet surface. I did not figure out how to capture the tablet events from all its surface mapping it to the widget client surface if it is not resized at full desktop size. (**Any help on this concern would be greatly apreciated.**)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class TabletSampleWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabletSampleWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pen_is_down = False
        self.pen_x = 0
        self.pen_y = 0
        self.pen_pressure = 0
        self.text = ""
        # Resizing the sample window to full desktop size:
        frame_rect = app.desktop().frameGeometry()
        width, height = frame_rect.width(), frame_rect.height()
        self.resize(width, height)
        self.move(-9, 0)
        self.setWindowTitle("Sample Tablet Event Handling")

    def tabletEvent(self, tabletEvent):
        self.pen_x = tabletEvent.globalX()
        self.pen_y = tabletEvent.globalY()
        self.pen_pressure = int(tabletEvent.pressure() * 100)
        if tabletEvent.type() == QTabletEvent.TabletPress:
            self.pen_is_down = True
            self.text = "TabletPress event"
        elif tabletEvent.type() == QTabletEvent.TabletMove:
            self.pen_is_down = True
            self.text = "TabletMove event"
        elif tabletEvent.type() == QTabletEvent.TabletRelease:
            self.pen_is_down = False
            self.text = "TabletRelease event"
        self.text += " at x={0}, y={1}, pressure={2}%,".format(self.pen_x, self.pen_y, self.pen_pressure)
        if self.pen_is_down:
            self.text += " Pen is down."
        else:
            self.text += " Pen is up."
        tabletEvent.accept()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        text = self.text
        i = text.find("\n\n")
        if i >= 0:
            text = text.left(i)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.TextAntialiasing)
        painter.drawText(self.rect(), Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft , text)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainform = TabletSampleWindow()
mainform.show()
app.exec_()
```